# Stream geometry points into kafka topic using kafka JDBC source connector

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, postgis, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to stream a table from `PostgreSQL` to Kafka topic using `Kafka JDBC connector`.
This table contains a geometry column with data type `Point`

Here is my JDBC connector configuration:

```
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-jdbc-pg-00/config \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "connector.class"                    : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url"                     : "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres",
    "connection.user"                    : "me",
    "connection.password"                : "12345",
    "topic.prefix"                       : "pg-",
    "mode"                               : "bulk",
    "poll.interval.ms"                   : 3600000
}'
```

The connector is running successfully, but when I check the topic, the geometry column is missing.

Is it possible to stream geospatial data using Kafka JDBC connectors?
Does anyone have any advice?

**UPDATE 2021-04-12**

I can see the `postgis-jdbc-2.5.0.jar` had been installed properly in this directory:

```sh
cd /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib
```

But when I checked the kafka-connect log, it seemed that the postgis jdbc plugin was not working properly,

```sh
kafka-connect      | [2021-04-11 23:38:25,275] WARN [source-jdbc-pg-00|task-0] JDBC type 1111 ("public"."geometry") not currently supported (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect:1153)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why it would be missing, but maybe try seeing if Debezium works better

Comment: OMG, I tried debezium first, but its source connector was even not able to connect to PostgreSQL. I planned to figure out the JDBC connector first and then work out the debezium one. These GIS things are driving me crazy......

Comment: You need to enable a few things on the database for it to work, but it probably also wouldn't be able to load custom types... Is there any way you can add a `query` config that can cast the point values to a Lat/Long floating point?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Would the geometry type still be a custom type if I install the PostGIS JDBC plugin? Unfortunately, I can't query and cast lat/long because my table only contains a geometry column.

Comment: I think `type 1111` just means some unknown type to the driver, so yes. In any case, I'm not understanding your log correctly (`PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect:1153`) because the Dialect class doesn't have more than 500 lines. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.java#L219  Also not seeing any Github issues referring to this problem

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am using debeizum as source connector and confluent as Sink connector for streaming psotgresql table with geometry column. I see there are missing data ( especially when there are negative co-ordinates)